# Running ng e2e on Protractor with Cucumber in Angular gives EPERM: operation not permitted, rename error

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor, cucumber, e2e

I'm trying to use Protractor with Cucumber for an E2E testing on an Angular project. I have protractor v5.4.4 installed. The first time I ran `ng e2e` the tests ran successfully, the second time I got this error:

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\dmdum\Projects\angular-project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver.exe' -> 'C:\Users\dmdum\Projects\angular-project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_96.0.4664.45.exe'
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\dmdum\Projects\angular-project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver.exe' -> 'C:\Users\dmdum\Projects\angular-project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_96.0.4664.45.exe'
    at Object.renameSync (fs.js:741:3)
    at unzip (C:\Users\dmdum\Projects\angular-project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cmds\update.js:240:8)
    at C:\Users\dmdum\Projects\angular-project\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cmds\update.js:205:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

`chromedriver_96.0.4664.45.exe` already exists in the specified path

For me to run the tests successfully again, I would need to delete the `selenium` folder specified in the path and then run `npx webdriver-manager update` again and then `ng e2e`

But that's not a very good way to deal with the issue. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your webdriver is not properly installed, try running this in your project root to clean and get all web drivers:
`npx webdriver-manager update`

You can also add it as a `postinstall` script in your `package.json` so it's run after each `npm i` (or `npm ci`):

package.json:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "update-webdriver": "npx webdriver-manager update",
    "postinstall": "echo 'Now updating web drivers' && npm run update-webdriver",
    ...
}
...
```